# List of last generated file on each day from 7 days list

Tags: shell, unix

I've a list of files in the following format:

```
Group_2012_01_06_041505.csv
Region_2012_01_06_041508.csv
Region_2012_01_06_070007.csv
XXXX_YYYY_MM_DD_HHMMSS.csv
```

What is the best way to compile a list of last generated file for each day per group from last 7 days list?

Version that worked on HP-UX

```
for d in 6 5 4 3 2 1 0
do
    DATES[d]=$(perl -e "use POSIX;print strftime '%Y_%m_%d%',localtime time-86400*$d;")
done

for group in `ls *.csv | cut -d_ -f1 | sort -u`
do
    CSV_FILES=$working_dir/*.csv
    if [ ! -f $CSV_FILES ]; then
        break # if no file exists do not attempt processing
    fi
    for d in "${DATES[@]}"
    do
        file_nm=$(ls ${group}_$d* 2>>/dev/null | sort -r | head -1)
        if [ "$file_nm" != "" ]
        then
            # Process file
        fi
    done
done
```

Comment: Do you want to group by any prefix (Group, Region, XXXX, ...) from the example or just for the lines prefixed with Group_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can explicitly iterate over the group/time combinations:

```
for d in {1..6}
do
    DATES[d]=`gdate +"%Y_%m_%d" -d "$d day ago"`
done

for group in `ls *csv | cut -d_ -f1 | sort -u`
do
    for d in "${DATES[@]}"
    do
        echo "$group $d: " `ls ${group}_$d* 2>>/dev/null | sort -r | head -1`
    done
done
```

Which outputs the following for your example data set:

```
Group 2012_01_06:  Group_2012_01_06_041505.csv
Group 2012_01_05: 
Group 2012_01_04: 
Group 2012_01_03: 
Group 2012_01_02: 
Group 2012_01_01: 
Region 2012_01_06:  Region_2012_01_06_070007.csv
Region 2012_01_05: 
Region 2012_01_04: 
Region 2012_01_03: 
Region 2012_01_02: 
Region 2012_01_01: 
XXXX 2012_01_06: 
XXXX 2012_01_05: 
XXXX 2012_01_04: 
XXXX 2012_01_03: 
XXXX 2012_01_02: 
XXXX 2012_01_01:
```

Note `Region_2012_01_06_041508.csv` is not shown for Region 2012_01_06 as it is older than `Region_2012_01_06_070007.csv`

Comment: Thank you! Had to fix for d in {1..6} and gdate part since both were not working on HP-UX. Updated question with my version.

Comment: @Raj: Please see [ParsingLs](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) for reasons why you shouldn't.